# Show that something is a subsystem of a complete linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have a simple and basic question concerning degree of projective curves and I'm referring to something I've read on Miranda's book, *Algebraic curves and Riemann Surfaces*, Chapter VII, 3. The Degree of Projective Curves.

Suppose that $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ is a smooth nondegenerate curve such that $\text{deg}(X)=d$.
This means that given any hyperplane $H\subset \mathbb P^n$, the hyperplane divisor $D:=\text{div}(H)$ on $X$ has exactly degree $d$. Take the complete linear system $|D|$, we want to conclude that $\dim |D|\geq n$. So, let $Q$ be the set of hyperplane divisors on $X$: $$Q:=\{\text{div}(L)\in \text{Div}(X): L \text{ is an hyperplane}\}.$$

Now Miranda says that $Q$ is indeed a *subsystem* of the complete linear system $|D|$. It's clear that $Q\subseteq |D|$, but I don't understand why $Q$ is a subsystem. To see that it is a subsystem, I should show that there exists a linear subspace $V$ of $L(D)$ such that $Q=S(\mathbb P(V))$ where $$S\colon \mathbb P(L(D))\to |D|, [f]\mapsto \text{div}(f)+D$$ is the standard bijection between these two spaces. Who is $V$? Is there a more direct way to say that $Q$ is a subsystem?
 I'm sure this is really simple, but I'm quite new to Algebraic Geometry so if someone could help me I would appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid notational confusion: by $\mathbb PW^\vee$ I mean the set of one-dimensional linear *subspaces* of $W$, namely the quotient $(W\setminus\{0\})/k^\times$.

If I am not mistaken, in your notation $D=H\cap X$, a hyperplane section. Your $V$ is then the image of the restriction map $\rho:H^0(\mathbb P^n,\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^n}(1))\to H^0(X,\mathscr O_X(1))$. This map $\rho$ takes a degree one form $h$ on $\mathbb P^n$ (i.e. a linear homogeneous polynomial $h=\sum_{0\leq i\leq n} a_ix_i$) to its restriction to $X$.

The inclusion $V\subset H^0(X,\mathscr O_X(1))$ gives a surjection $H^0(X,\mathscr O_X(1))^\vee\to V^\vee$ and hence a closed immersion $$\mathbb PV^\vee\subset \mathbb PH^0(X,\mathscr O_X(1))^\vee,$$
which is your $Q\subset |D|$.

**Added**. Disregard all the above! Now, $|D|$ is the projective space whose points correspond to effective divisors on $X$ which are linearly equivalent to $D=H\cap X$. It is the projectivisation of (the dual of) $L(D)$. Now, in $L(D)$ you can consider the subspace $V\subset L(D)$ consisting of elements arising as restrictions of homogeneous degree one forms $$h=\sum_{0\leq i\leq n} a_ix_i.$$ Note that such forms (which live on $\mathbb P^n$) are exactly those whose zero loci are hyperplanes $L\subset\mathbb P^n$. But this says exactly that $Q$ is the projectivisation of (the dual) of $V$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't understand what you are saying because my knowledge in algebraic geometry is very little. I don't know what is the map you're talking about. Isn't there a  simpler way to prove it?

Comment: Claretta, I hope now it is clearer. Let me know if not.

Comment: I still have few doubts, but I think it is just me. For example, $h \in L(D) \iff div(h)\geq -D$. How can I say that this is true?

Comment: You do not have to check it, because $V$ already lives inside $L(D)$ by definition. Please ask all that troubles you, I will do my best to make my answer understandable.

Comment: In $L(D)$ we have all meromorphic functions with poles bounded by $D$. So you take $V$, which is made by linear equations. I don't understand why you're saying that $V$ is already in $L(D)$. And also if it were, I don't understand your conclusion when you say "$Q$ is the projectivisation on $V$". Thanks again  and sorry for my delay in answering.